# How to rename a file with the time by comparing 2 time ranges using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to rename a file downloaded with date and time as below

my_file_2022-04-06_15.csv

[image]

The logic I want here is:
if the file was downloaded between 3.00pm - 4.00pm then it should be renamed as 15 as mentioned in the image , if it is downloaded between 6.00pm - 7.00pm then 18.

I tried this

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('powershell -NoL -NoP -Command "(Get-Date).Hour"') DO (SET /A "HOUR=%%a")
IF %HOUR% LSS 16 (
set h = 15
)

else if %HOUR% LSS 19 (
set h = 18
)
```

It didn't work

Comment: 1. The `else` keyword must be on the same physical line as the `)` closing the if-true command. 2. The spaces in a straight `set` command are significant. The variable being set is `h[Space]`, not `h` and the value `[Space]18`. If you use `set /a` then you can use the syntax you've posted.

Comment: @Magoo Thanks, It was because of the space yes, It worked , Thank you